# Shifting rows in R

Tags: r

My data is as follows:

```
 1    2    3    4    5
 0    1    2    3    4
 0    0    1    2    3
 0    0    0    0    1
 0    0    0    0    1
```

How can I make the data so that it will look like this:

```
 1    2    3    4    5
 1    2    3    4    0
 1    2    3    0    0
 0    1    0    0    0
 1    0    0    0    0
```

So that the first row don't shift, the second row shifted left by 1, third row shifted left by 2, fourth row shifted left by 3, and last row shifted left by 4?

I tried to at first shift all the rows below the first row to the left by 1, but apparently, it doesn't work.

```
nc  <- ncol(df)
df[-(1), 2:nc] <- df[-(1), 2:(nc+1)]
df[-(1), 10] <- 0
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `shift` function from `data.table` with `fill = 0`. If you want the output as a `data.frame`, put `data.frame()` around the last line.

```
mat <- as.matrix(df)
library(data.table)
t(sapply(seq(nrow(mat)), function(i) shift(mat[i,], i - 1, 'lead', fill = 0)))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]    1    2    3    4    0
# [3,]    1    2    3    0    0
# [4,]    0    1    0    0    0
# [5,]    1    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option:

```
m <- as.matrix(read.table(text = "1    2    3    4    5
0    1    2    3    4
0    0    1    2    3
0    0    0    0    1
0    0    0    0    1"))

do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(1:nrow(m)), 
                      function(i) {c(m[i, i:ncol(m)], rep(0, i-1))}))

#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#[1,]  1  2  3  4  5
#[2,]  1  2  3  4  0
#[3,]  1  2  3  0  0
#[4,]  0  1  0  0  0
#[5,]  1  0  0  0  0
```